# Why do I receive an error that says 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.' for auto layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, ios-autolayout

[image]I am trying to pin a button on all 4 sides to fix a button object at the exact location that I arbitrarily placed it at, but I am getting the following error when I run it. Any insight or help would be really appreciated.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out     which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x9f494b0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f40370(20)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x9f3b6c0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f40370]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9f3feb0 )>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x9f418e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f407c0(0)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x9f18010 _UILayoutGuide:0x9f407c0.bottom == UIView:0x9f3feb0.bottom>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9f40f10 V:[UIButton:0x9f40f40'Button']-(211)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f407c0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9f47ab0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f40370]-(539)-[UIButton:0x9f40f40'Button']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa157b10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x9f3feb0(568)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You've got constraints that conflict with one another. You might want to post a screenshot of your Interface Builder view, as it's easier to visually determine where you've got constraints that may conflict. Interface Builder can be a PITA to deal with sometimes, but once you "get the hang of it" it's a big time saver.

Comment: @AdrianB Sorry. Just uploaded the screenshot. So I moved a button into the view and want it to be at that exact location. As mentioned, I pinned all 4 sides but getting the error. What would be the best way place an object to be at that exact location you want it to be? Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect to happen, if the view's size changes?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Sorry but not quiet getting what you are asking. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @KoKi I updated my answer. The error you're encountering isn't a huge deal--it's just telling you there's a conflict and Xcode resolved it for you. For what you've got, you just need to pin it to two sides, not 4. Alternatively, you could try playing around with the dimensions of the button.

Comment: @AdrianB understood it. ;-) When the size of the view changes, but the button should still have the same distance to all 4 sides, the only solution is, that the button changes in size. This might be okay for the horizontal direction, but is hard for a button in the vertical direction and definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you've got constraints that conflict with one another. You'll probably want to delete one of the constraints in Interface Builder to resolve it.

I suspect you may be new to iOS, so rather than a long, verbose answer, I would suggest you watch a tutorial on interface builder. [Here's one from Ray Wenderlich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J10vzrTcswI) you may find helpful:

**Update:**
Based on your screen shot, I would wager the size of your button is causing the issue. I think pinning to just the right side and the bottom would quell the error logged in your console. In the absence of other items in your scene, I don't think you need the top and left constraints.

**Update 2:**

Another tack to take would be to set your constraints using >= or <= instead of a hard-coded =. If you did the top as >=, the bottom constraint would be <=. If the left constraint is >=, the right would be <=.

**Update 3:**
Go to iTunesU and watch the demo for [Stanford University's course titled CS193P, Winter 2015](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/), **Lecture 1** towards the end.  He covers basic Autolayout in that lecture. Then watch **Lecture 8**, which covers Autolayout extensively. He explains everything very thoroughly there.

For Autolayout, it doesn't really matter whether you're working in Swift or Objective-C. Seeing it in action should clarify it quite a bit for you.

Comment: I did not hard-code anything yet and just used the constraints window and clicked to pin. I made the attempt to pin only the right and bottom, and it did show up on the simulation and no error log, but it's not at the exact location that it was located originally on the Storyboard. Also, when I spun the screen around to different views, the button just disappeared. Would there be a way to resolve those? Really appreciate your help Adrian!

Comment: I checked it out but I am not seeing Lecture 1. Is that where it's supposed to be located at? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even @AdrianB has a basic understanding of my comments in his answer, I will it explain it in detail here:

Let's say that the view has a size of 200 x 200, the button of 100 x 20. (Values only for having an example). So, i. e., you place it with a left space of 80, a right space of 20 (80+100+20=200) and a top space of 100, a bottom space of 80. (100+20+80=200).

Now the size of the view changes. It gets a width of 300. Your constraint for right and left are still valid. So the borders are still 80 and 20. The only way to realize that, is to give the button a width of 200. (80+200+20=300). Okay, maybe a funny looking button, but this works.

But it really becomes hard in the vertical direction, if the view's height changes to 300. The button has to grow in vertical direction to 120. This is the only way the top and bottom space stay valid. I do not think that buttons like that.

However it becomes impossible, when the view's height is less than 180, because all the space is consumed by your constraints (top=100+bottom=80=180) so there is no space for the bottom any more. Its height becomes negative.

That's the problem.

Now to the solution:

Do not place a button with hard constraints for all four edges in an auto layout. Auto layout is for changing the superviews size. In such a case, what you do is meaningless.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. So in the case I am trying to achieve, what should I do in order to resolve it? If I want to place it in that exact location?

Comment: First you have to define, what the "exact" location is after resizing. It is not a problem of the implementation, but of what you want. However, *you* have to say what should happen, if the window resizes: The button moves to the right, to the left or changes its width. This are the only solution in a *mathematical* way, you cannot change, because you cannot change mathematics. It is the same in vertical direction.

Comment: Understood! But in the case that I have shown in the image and I want it to be fix it in that same location, which is in the size of iPhone 6 plus view, and show it in that exact location when running on the simulation for iPhone 6 Plus. I just pinned the bottom and right, yet when I run the simulation, it still shows the button at a slightly different location. How would you approach it to achieve what I have described?

Comment: As I said: Change mathematics or make your decision.

Comment: By mathematics, do you mean calculate the points and size of the elements? If so I did yet it still does not fix at the point I'd like it for it to be. If you don't mind, could you guide me in showing how to resolve it?

Comment: No, I can't. None can. It is impossible. These are the options: a) No resizing at all. b) Changing the button's size . (You don't want that.) c) Giving up one fixed border constraint in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a button with 539 points from the top and 211 points from the bottom, that's 750 points in total, not including the button height. There's no iPhone screen with that size of a screen, the iPhone 6+ has a height of 736 points, you should adjust the 539, 211, and height of the button if you are going to hard code values and make sure they add up to the screen height of the iPhone you are sizing for.

This is a width constraint that is equal to 100 points:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_avatarImage
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                        multiplier:1.f
                                                          constant:100.f]];
```

This is a width constraint that is equal to 100 points:

```
 [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_avatarImage
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                        multiplier:1.f
                                                          constant:100.f]];
```

You can set other types of constraints as well, like this, center x:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_avatarImage
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                multiplier:1.f
                                                  constant:0.f]];
```

avatarImage is an imageview that is 100x100 and centered at the superviews center x, the y centering isn't shown, but I have a constraint for that as well.

here's a few of the macros I use to auto resize to iphone sizes, it basically auto resizes all views based on the largest view which is the iphone 6+, I only design for the iphone 6+ and then everything flows through, there's some anomalies sometimes, but this covers nearly everything, everything for programmatic views using hybrid auto layout and my own custom layout engine.

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)

#define MAX_SCREEN_HEIGHT_IS_IPHONE6_PLUS 736.00
#define MAX_SCREEN_WIDTH_IS_IPHONE6_PLUS 414.00

#define heightResizer(n) n/MAX_SCREEN_HEIGHT_IS_IPHONE6_PLUS*SCREEN_HEIGHT
#define widthResizer(n) n/MAX_SCREEN_WIDTH_IS_IPHONE6_PLUS*SCREEN_WIDTH
```

So, for an example, look at this constraint:

```
 [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_avatarImage
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                        multiplier:1.f
                                                          constant:100.f]];
```

Now, look at it again:

```
 [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_avatarImage
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                        multiplier:1.f
                                                          constant:heightResizer(100.0)]];
```

The hieght now resizes itself when the iPhone size is less than the iPhone 6+, this is the beauty of this macro, you can hard code some numbers, and others you can let the auto layout engine flex, both of these methods flex, and both are easy to use. There's some issues you'll have with the navigation bar heights and the tabbar controller heights, but if you know how to subclass those UI elements then they aren't a problem anymore. I sub class everything and I even subclass my own subclasses, so it make everything work nice with each other using this form of hybrid layout.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. My question is, why doesn't Xcode account for the object's height? Then the numbers showing in the constraints, what do they really represent? I thought they are supposed to be the spaces from the object to its the view's edges on all 4 sides.

Comment: You are right and you are wrong, some constrasits are for distances from top, bottom, left and right and some are actual height and width constraints, let me show, you but I don't use storyboard because it makes it hard to know what to do when you need to use code, re read my answer

Comment: In what I am trying to get to, just trying to fix that button at that location, for all iPhone devices, how would you approach it? If you don't mind, could you give a brief description? Would greatly appreciate it. I am about to pull my hair out to trying to figure out such a small problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know where I can view it?

Comment: yep, I'll post in about an hour,

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but please let me know when you get a chance to post it. Really trying to learn! Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, i forgot, sorry, one sec

Comment: Ko Ki, there you go, those macros should help you out, here's an example of the macros in use:   see my answer here for a custom Alert view, add it to your project and just call it whenever you want an alert view to pop up that is custom, it uses this auto layout method above and auto resizses to all iphone heights and widths.